# Android: The method getId() in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: android

I am trying to access the `cb` in the if statement but I am getting `cb cant be resolved`

I have tried declare `Checkbox cb` as class variable but I am getting `The method getId() in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int)`.

I tried to declare it as method local variable like `final CheckBox cb;` but I am getting two errors: The first one `The final local variable cb may already have been assigned` at this line `cb = new CheckBox(this);` and the second one `The method getId() in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

how can I fix that?

```
private void createCheckboxList(final ArrayList<Integer> items) {
    //final CheckBox cb;

    final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
        cb.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i)));
        cb.setId(i);
        ll.addView(cb);

    }
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 150));
    btn.setText("submit");
    ll.addView(btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i : items) {
                if (cb.getId(i).isChecked()) {

                }
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: view.getId() doesn't take arguments. It just returns the id for whatever view you're calling it on. Also, your `cb` is declared in this method, so `cb` won't exist outside the method, when your button `onClick()` is invoked.

Comment: And how can I fix that? since I have deleted the argument and I am getting two errors first one `The final local variable cb may already have been assigned` at this line ` cb = new CheckBox(this);` and the second one  `Cannot invoke isChecked() on the primitive type int` at this line `if (cb.getId().isChecked()) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The reference cb wont exist outside the 'for' loop. Since you know its id you can create a new checkbox reference and use findviewById(); to get refer to the same checkbox
2. cb.getId() returns and integer not a checkbox reference

   ```
   final LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lila);
   for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
   final CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
   cb.setText(String.valueOf(items.get(i)));
   cb.setId(i);
   ll.addView(cb);

   }
   Button btn = new Button(this);
   btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 150));
   btn.setText("submit");
   ll.addView(btn);

   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       for (int i = 0; i < items.size()) {   \\
            Checkbox ch=(Checkbox) findViewById(i);  \\
           if (ch.isChecked()) {

           }
       }

   }
   });

   }
   ```

Comment: How can I store the selected vlaues (and not the id) of checkboxes into ArrayList<Integer>? for example 1. 4;  2. 7; 3.10; 4. 13 so he he selected the id 2 and 3 I want to store the values (7,10) into arrayList.

Comment: I have declared it as in your answer but when I click the button the app crashes and  I am getting `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference`